# Easy steps to use CMU sphinx4

Tags: cmusphinx

I want to use CMU sphinx4 to transcribe a given audio file. It should take an audio file in .wav format and having conversation in **Indian English**. I am new to CMUSphinx and can't get easy step wise description of the process.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look into the transcriber demo provided with the sphinx api.

You can just change the language model and the acoustic model, configure the same in the config.xml file, and use the same code.

1. The language model- depending on the use-case of your application, you can use the WSJ language model having 5k words, or you can make your own model.To make your own landuage model, you can read more [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm). One easy way is to use the lmtool. google "lmtool cmu"
2. The acoustic model- As you want to have an application for Indian accent, you need to have audio files for Indian english, and the corresponding transcription file. Based on your use-case, you can either train your own acoustic model, or you can adapt an existing acoustic model. read more [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam). you can also search data sets online.
3. Configure things in the config.xml file so your application uses your language and acoustic model.

For a beginner, these steps might be helpful-

1. Read about sphinx architecture and try demos
2. Study about what the language model is.
3. Read about how to construct the language model. (lmtool, cmuclmtk, etc)
4. Read about what the acoustic model is.
5. Read about how to train/adapt the acoustic model.
6. Configure the config.xml file in your java application to use these models.